# No module 'zlib' for Python 2.6

Tags: python, zlib, easy-install

When I start Python 2.7, I can `import zlib` without a problem. Unfortunately, I need Python 2.6 for a specific project.

I tried installing it with this script I wrote:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
mkdir /tmp/shell_scripts
cd /tmp/shell_scripts
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.9/Python-2.6.9.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-2.6.9.tgz
rm Python-2.6.9.tgz
cd Python-2.6.9
./configure --with-zlib
make
make install
./python setup.py install
cd /tmp
rm -r shell_scripts
```

When I type `import zlib`, I get an import error. I need `zlib` to install `easy_install`. Have you an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `which python` says `/usr/local/bin/python` and starts Python 2.6.9, `which python2.6` says `/usr/local/bin/python2.6` and also starts Python 2.6.9. Python prints `Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Feb 28 2014, 22:49:43)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution in a blog: I had to build a symbolic link and set an environment variable. This is my working code:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
cd /lib
sudo ln -s i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 libz.so

mkdir /tmp/shell_scripts
cd /tmp/shell_scripts
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.9/Python-2.6.9.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-2.6.9.tgz
rm Python-2.6.9.tgz
cd Python-2.6.9
make distclean
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)"
./configure
make
make install
./python setup.py install
unset LDFLAGS
cd /tmp
rm -r shell_scripts
```

Now, `import zlib` no longer throws an error.

Comment: In my case `libz.so.1` was located at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1` (Debian 8.0 jessie).

Comment: Adding  
`ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 libz.so` and  
`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)"`  
did the trick for me when installing Python 2.7.1 on Debian Buster.